# Shorten F# Tuple Matching

Tags: f#, pattern-matching

F# beginner here.

I am trying to match a tuple with several cases and return a specific value on the matching condition. This is how it looks:

```
match inf, sup with
            | nan , _  
            | _ , nan  
                -> Interval(nan,nan) 

            | _ , _  when inf = -infinity && sup = -infinity -> Interval(nan,nan) 
            | _ , _  when inf = infinity && sup = infinity -> Interval(nan,nan)

            | _ , _  when inf > sup -> Interval(nan,nan)         

            | _ , _ -> Interval(inf,sup)
```

Since almost every case returns Interval(nan,nan) I would like to group them due to readability, but I have no idea how. I tried the following

```
match inf, sup with
            | nan , _  
            | _ , nan  
            | _ , _  when inf = -infinity && sup = -infinity
            | _ , _  when inf = infinity && sup = infinity
            | _ , _  when inf > sup -> Interval(nan,nan) 
                -> Interval(nan,nan)

            | _ , _ -> Interval(inf,sup)
```

but the compiler says

> The two sides of this 'or' pattern bind different sets of varibales

So I tried the following:

```
match inf, sup with
            | nan , _  
            | _ , nan  
                -> Interval(nan,nan)
            | _ , _  when inf = -infinity && sup = -infinity
            | _ , _  when inf = infinity && sup = infinity
            | _ , _  when inf > sup -> Interval(nan,nan) 
                -> Interval(nan,nan)

            | _ , _ -> Interval(inf,sup)
```

Here I get an error at the second | from the second when clause. He expects an '->' or other token.

So: How can I shorten this matching or how can I improve it? Those several Interval(nan,nan) seem uneccesary to me.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I doubt the behavior of `| nan , _ | _ , nan` is what you're hoping it is...

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN

Answer (score 5):

You are not checking `nan` correctly.  Matching against `nan` will result in any supplied value being bound to a value called `nan`.  Notice in FSI:

> ```
> let isNan x = match x with |nan -> true |_ -> false;;
>
> let isNan x = match x with |nan -> true |_ -> false;;
> -----------------------------------------^
>
> stdin(1,42): warning FS0026: This rule will never be matched
> ```

You should check for `nan` values by using `System.Double.IsNaN(x)`.

Bearing this in mind, I would use an active pattern to check for non-valid values:

```
let (|PositiveInfinity|NegativeInfinity|NaN|Real|) = function
    |v when v = -infinity -> NegativeInfinity
    |v when v = infinity -> PositiveInfinity
    |v when System.Double.IsNaN(v) -> NaN
    |v -> Real v
```

Then reduce your pattern match to:

```
let test inf sup =
    match inf, sup with
    |NaN, _
    |_, NaN
    |NegativeInfinity, NegativeInfinity
    |PositiveInfinity, PositiveInfinity
    |_, _ when inf > sup -> Interval(nan, nan)
    |_, _  -> Interval(inf, sup)
```

Comment: Upvote for pointing out that the NaN checking is not working as excepted - however, your solution does not match the semantics of the original question. Posting a new answer.

Comment: @AntonSchwaighofer You are correct.  I have modified my answer.

Answer (score 3):

In match statement `when` clause is common for all or cases that are listed before. If you want to visualize this, you can think like there are parens like this:

```
( | Case1 n
  | Case2 n
  | Case3 n ) when predicate(n) ->
```

You cannot repeat `when` clause few times before you have result expression (after `->`).

Instead you could join all conditions in one `when` clause, something similar to:

```
| _ when cond1 ||
         cond2 ||
         cond3 -> ...
```

Answer (score 3):

The answer given by @TheInnerLight is great, but handles a corner case differently. The OP considered an interval between (-inf, 10.0) as valid, but the posted answer does not. Here's an answer that handles all cases the same:

```
let (|PositiveInfinity|NegativeInfinity|NaN|Real|) = function
    | v when Double.IsPositiveInfinity v -> PositiveInfinity
    | v when Double.IsNegativeInfinity v -> NegativeInfinity
    | v when Double.IsNaN v -> NaN
    | v -> Real v

let getInterval inf sup =
    match inf, sup with
    | NaN, _ 
    | _ , NaN
    | NegativeInfinity, NegativeInfinity
    | PositiveInfinity, PositiveInfinity 
    | _ , _  when inf > sup -> Interval(nan,nan) 
    | _ , _ -> Interval(inf,sup)
```

Slightly off topic: I would generally advise against using `NaN` as a marker for invalid intervals. Any comparisons with `NaN` return false, meaning you need to handle them differently in each interval check. Consider the following 2 versions of writing "is a point `v` inside an interval?", where lower and upper bound happen to be `NaN`:

```
let inside1 v = v >= nan && v <= nan
let inside2 v = not (v < nan || v > nan)
```

In `inside1`, you check "is the point inside?", in `inside2`, you ask "is it not outside?". Checking the point 1.0 gives:

```
> inside1 1.0;;
val it : bool = false
> inside2 1.0;;
val it : bool = true
```

I would hence suggest that your function returns an `Interval option`, meaning `None` in all cases where you presently return `Interval(nan,nan)`. Otherwise, your code will be littered by explicit `NaN` checks all over.

Answer (score 1):

Just use the Boolean or `||` in the `when` clauses:

```
match inf, sup with
        | nan , _  
        | _ , nan  
            -> Interval(nan,nan) 
        | _ , _  when inf = -infinity && sup = -infinity ||
                      inf = infinity  && sup = infinity ||
                      inf > sup -> Interval(nan,nan)       
        | _ , _ -> Interval(inf,sup)
```